# AWS Cloudformation subnet association does not work for all routing tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I created a CF template with 6 subnets. 3 per AZ.

2x Public Subnets

- Contain a Nat GW each

4x Private Subnets

- 1 Private Routetable per AZ for HA

The stack creation works fine. Everything green with no errors reported.
The subnet associations reported as create_complete.

Unfortunatelly I get no subnets in one routing table (PrivateRouteTableA). All the other route tables get the right associations.
The subnets that should be associated with the PrivateRouteTableA are still using the main route table.

Here is the snippet:

```
# Route Table for AZ B --> NAT Gateway B
  PrivateInetRoutetableB:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref BlubVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "PrivateInetRoutetableB"
        - Key: "Project"
          Value: "Blub"
        - Key: "EnvironmentInfra"
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentInfra
    DependsOn: BlubIgwAttachment
  PrivateDefaultRouteB:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateInetRoutetableB
      DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGwB
    DependsOn: BlubIgwAttachment
  PrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssocB:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateInetRoutetableB
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1B
    DependsOn: BlubIgwAttachment
  PrivateSubnet2RouteTableAssocB:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateInetRoutetableB
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2B
    DependsOn: NBlubIgwAttachment

  # Route Table for AZ A --> NAT Gateway A
  PrivateInetRoutetableA:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref BlubVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "PrivateInetRoutetableA"
        - Key: "Project"
          Value: "Blub"
        - Key: "EnvironmentInfra"
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentInfra
    DependsOn: BlubIgwAttachment
  PrivateDefaultRouteA:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateInetRoutetableA
      DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGwA
    DependsOn: BlubIgwAttachment
  PrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssocA:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateInetRoutetableA
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1A
    DependsOn: BlubIgwAttachment
  PrivateSubnet2RouteTableAssocA:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateInetRoutetableA
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2A
    DependsOn: BlubIgwAttachment
```

I was not able to find any difference from A to B and I didn't find someone describing a similar issue. I hope you guys can provide some suggestions what I could try next.

Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Comment: Possible typo in `PrivateSubne2tRouteTableAssocA`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But this is just a typo that ended up in the post because i had to replace the actual names for the forum post

Comment: I didn't think it was referenced anywhere, but it was all that I saw.  Since you are having to sanitize this for posting in the question, you could be subconsciously fixing a bug when you do that -- if it's possible, I'd suggest that you try using your sanitized version to create the stack, so that what's in the question is precisely the same as what you're actually running.

Comment: I used the sanitized version with the same result. The strange thing is that I don't get an error on the creation of the associations but still it is not created properly.